# Pandas series to numpy array conversion error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas series with foll. `value_counts` output():

```
NaN     2741
 197    1891
 127     188
 194      42
 195      24
 122      21
```

When I perform describe() on this series, I get:

```
df[col_name].describe()
count    2738.000000
mean      172.182250
std        47.387496
min         0.000000
25%       171.250000
50%       197.000000
75%       197.000000
max       197.000000
Name: SS_D_1, dtype: float64
```

However, if I try to find minimum and maximum, I get nan as answer:

```
numpy.min(df[col_name].values)
nan
```

Also, when I try t convert it to a numpy array, I seem to get an array with only nan's

```
numpy.array(df[col_name])
```

Any suggestion on how to convert from pandas series to numpy array succesfully

Comment: `df[col_name].values` will return the numpy array.  If you have a NaN in the data, it gets propagated using the numpy.min function.  Meaning if there is a NaN, np.min will always yield the NaN as the anser.  Try nanmin  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html#numpy.nanmin

Comment: The `min` of any array containing `nan` is also `nan`.  To ignore `nan` values, try `np.nanmin(df[col_name].values)` (or just `df[col_name].min()`).

Comment: Thanks, but I also get a nan for this: numpy.array(df[col_name]).min()

Comment: The problem is that you're casting it to a numpy array before calling the `min()` method. `pandas.Series.min()` does the equivalent of `np.nanmin` and ignores nan values, whereas `numpy.ndarray.min` does the equivalent of `np.min` and will return `nan` for an array that contains one or more `nan`s.

Comment: great, ty. if you can write this as an answer, i will be happy to accept

Comment: @user308827 - as of pandas' 0.24.0 - you can access the backing array of a pandas Series with `.array` and `.to_numpy` - please find an updated answer bellow. [pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the function [`np.min`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin) and the method `np.ndarray.min` will always return NaN for any array that contains one or more NaN values (this is standard IEE754 floating point behaviour).

You could use [`np.nanmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html), which ignores NaN values when computing the min, e.g.:

```
np.nanmin(df[col_name].values)
```

An even simpler option is just to use the [`pd.Series.min()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html) method, which already ignores NaN values, i.e.:

```
df[col_name].min()
```

I have no idea why `numpy.array(df[col_name])` would return an array containing only NaNs, unless `df[col_name]` already contained only NaNs to begin with. I assume this must be due to some other mistake in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As of pandas' v 0.24.0 - you can access the backing array of a pandas Series with `.array` and `.to_numpy`

[pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index)
Quote: "**Series.array** and Index.array have been added for extracting the array backing a Series or Index... We haven’t removed or deprecated Series.values or DataFrame.values, but we **highly recommend and using .array or .to_numpy()** instead

... We recommend using Series.array when you need the array of data stored in the Series, **and Series.to_numpy() when you know you need a NumPy array.**"