# Transforming a Pandas dataframe to numpy array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

**Scenario:** As the question title implies I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe to a numpy array. The dataframe has normal 2d data, just numbers. From other questions here in SO (such as [Strange error during conversion from Panda Dataframe to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487801/strange-error-during-conversion-from-panda-dataframe-to-numpy-array) [Pandas series to numpy array conversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406265/pandas-series-to-numpy-array-conversion-error) [Spyder Python "object arrays are currently not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494358/spyder-python-object-arrays-are-currently-not-supported)) and from the documentation I wrote the code. But apparently my problem is slightly different from those questions:

**Problem:** The code runs normally, and I can see the array in the variable explorer, but when I try to open it it yields:

> Object arrays are currently not supported.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

**Obs:** I am running python 2.7 on Spyder.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
inp_file = df 
compofile ="Co"
yieldfile = "Y"
maturityfile = "T"
countryfile ="Cou"


'#importing excel files

'co1 = pd.read_excel(inp_file,sheetname=cofile)
'y1 = pd.read_excel(inp_file,sheetname=yfile)
'm1 = pd.read_excel(inp_file,sheetname=mfile)
'cou1 = pd.read_excel(inp_file,sheetname=coufile)

co2 = inp_file.as_matrix()
```

Comment: As we don't have this `.xlsx` file read in your code, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Alfe Altered to include a random pd dataframe that can be replicated. result is the same.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Could you restart Spyder and try again.

Comment: @KRKirov Just did that and also restarted the pc. Same result.

Comment: I am running python-3.6 but am positive that I have had the same problem with Spyder as you. Can you at least print your numpy array?

Comment: @KRKirov I can do all operations with it and print it in the kernel, just cannot open it from the variable explorer.

Comment: You can just call `.get_values()` on your pandas `DataFrame`.  That will return the 2D numpy array of the values therein.  `.as_matrix()` works for me as well.  I guess you have a different problem.  I suggest you try to reproduce your problem yourself in a minimal system (Python interpreter on command line, etc.) without all your surrounding system stuff.